# Matrix Condition Number Definition

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Wikipedia lists the condition number at x of any function $f: V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ between Banach spaces to be $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \sup_{||\delta x|| \le \epsilon} \left[ \frac{||f(x+\delta x) -f(x)||}{||f(x)||} / \frac{||\delta x||}{||x||}\right]$

However, it seems to me that this would give any linear operator a condition number of one? So I'm having trouble reconciling this with the notion of matrix condition number

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
f(x):=A^{-1}x,
$$
then
$$
\frac{\|f(x+\delta x)-f(x)\|}{\|f(x)\|}/
\frac{\|\delta x\|}{\|x\|}
=
\frac{\|A^{-1}(x+\delta x)-A^{-1}x\|}{\|A^{-1}x\|}/
\frac{\|\delta x\|}{\|x\|}
=
\frac{\|A^{-1}\delta x\|}{\|\delta x\|}
\frac{\|x\|}{\|A^{-1}x\|},
$$
so
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\sup_{\|\delta x\|\leq\epsilon}
\frac{\|A^{-1}\delta x\|}{\|\delta x\|}
\frac{\|x\|}{\|A^{-1}x\|}
=
\|A^{-1}\|
\frac{\|x\|}{\|A^{-1}x\|}.
$$
Note that the condition number depends on the "right-hand side" $x$. To eliminate this dependency and thus to obtain the "worst-case" condition number, we want to maximize it over all nonzero $x$ which gives the classical matrix condition number:
$$
\sup_{x\neq 0}
\|A^{-1}\|
\frac{\|x\|}{\|A^{-1}x\|}
=
\|A^{-1}\|
\sup_{y\neq 0}
\frac{\|Ay\|}{\|y\|}
=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|.
$$