# Condition number of matrix proof

Tags: matrices, self-learning, condition-number

The condition of a differentiable function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is defined as $$\kappa = \frac{\Vert x\Vert_X}{\Vert f(x)\Vert_Y}\Vert Df(x)\Vert_{\leadsto Y},$$
where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_X$ is the norm defined on $X$, $\Vert\cdot\Vert_Y$ the norm defined on $Y$, and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\leadsto Y}$ the norm induced by $\Vert\cdot\Vert_Y$.

The condition of a regular matrix $A$ is defined as $k = \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_{\leadsto X} \Vert A\Vert_{\leadsto X}$. I want to show that this is a special case of the aforementioned general case if $f(x) = Ax$. I have managed to show that $$\kappa\leq k$$
using the submultiplicativity of norms: $$\kappa = \frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert A\Vert}\leq \frac{\Vert A^{-1}\Vert \Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\Vert A\Vert  = \Vert A^{-1}\Vert \Vert A\Vert = k$$
(ignoring the norm subscripts in the notation). However, I fail to work out the other ineqality: $$\kappa = \frac{\Vert x\Vert}{\Vert Ax\Vert}\Vert A\Vert\geq \qquad?\qquad\geq k$$

Does this inequality even hold? I am aware of [Matrix Condition Number Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641028/matrix-condition-number-definition), however, in that answer it seems that the two notions of condition numbers $k$ and $\kappa$ are just related and not the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof**

$$\kappa=\frac{\|x\|}{\|Ax\|}\|A\|_{ip}\ge\frac{\|x\|}{\|A\|_{ip}\|x\|}\|A\|_{ip}\\
=1\\
=\|I\|_{ip}\\
=\|A^{-1}A\|_{ip}\\
\ge \|A^{-1}\|\|A\|\\
=k$$

Comment: Apparently, this proof is not correct: the inequalty $\Vert A^{-1}A\Vert \geq \Vert A\Vert \Vert A^{-1}\Vert$ used in the second last step is wrong (it should point in the other direction: $\Vert AB\Vert\leq \Vert A\Vert \Vert B\Vert$)